# mapped network drive

Tags: network-shares

I have a mapped network drive which required a password to be able to map it.  Is there anyway to find out the passowrd which i used to map it initialy.

It is currently stored so i can access all the files and folders on the drive but i want to add the same network drive on another computer but cannot remember the password set for it.  I am unable to access the network resource to reset the password.

Does windows store these credentials anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [Nirsoft Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) tool...

[image: Nirsoft]